# objective c type casting an object based on an NSString class name

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an issue where I am getting in an object of type id. i know its base type is an NSManagedObject but the custom attributes for whatever type it actually is (name, email, etc) are what i really need. in the long run, i am trying to make one method that will turn my custom NSManagedObjects into NSDictionaries. maybe i am going down the wrong path in general but....

If i have something like

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)obj{
...
Class someClass = NSClassFromString([[obj class] description]);
...
```

i can get the class from that but then i cannot really figure out how to cast my object as that class.

ideally this would be the next few lines of that code

```
someClass* myObject = (someClass*)obj;
NSArray *keys = [[[myObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
NSDictionary *dict = [myObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
//do something with dict
...
```

but i cannot figure out how to get an object of the type someClass. I have seen where you can use the NSClassFromString object for an alloc init call like

```
id someObject = [[className alloc] init];
```

but that will not work for this situation as i already have an object passed in that I need. any ideas / criticisms? I am really trying to avoid a crap load of if statements for all of my items but it may be the quickest way right now...

Comment: I guess a better, more concise, way of asking the question (sans code examples) would be: Is there a dynamic way to pass in custom objects with NSManagedObject as its subclass, and get back an NSDictionary of all the fields from my custom object?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to cast to some dynamic type?  Objective-C is dynamically typed, and it makes no difference (other than to the compiler syntax checker) what type pointer is used when you make a call -- oops, excuse me -- "send a message".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are all NSManagedObject subclasses, and all you will be calling on them is valueForKey or other methods that are implemented by NSManagedObject, just cast to NSManagedObject. If I'm missing something, please let me know.

In answer to your comment on the original question - you already have this in your sample:

```
NSDictionary *myObjectDictionary = [[myObject entity] attributesByName];
```

This gives you a dictionary containing all the attributes of your managed object, with the attribute name as the key in each case. You then use these keys to call valueForKey on your object.

Perhaps a point I need to make is that it is fine to cast an object as its superclass, if you are not going to call any subclass specific methods on it.

Comment: I have custom classes that subclass NSManagedObject. and in those custom classes are the things that I need for the dictionary keys.

Comment: OK, things that aren't just attributes from your data model?

Comment: no, they are attributes from the data model, just i am trying to use this method for all of my custom classes to convert the object I pass it into a dictionary.

Comment: Does my updated answer help? You're nearly there with what's in your question, I think - you just need to cycle through the keys returned in attributesByName and call valueForKey on your object, then put the result into a dictionary.

Comment: ok, im dumb. i thought that by casting to its superclass, i would lose the data model atributes. casting to NSManagedObjects works fine. sorry for being so confusing, its been a long day..

Answer (score 1):

If your sole goal is to convert an object (`id`) into a dictionary.  Since you stated that you know they are all instances of `NSManagedObject`, you can safely cast it:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)object {
  NSManagedObject* managedObject = (NSManagedObject *)object;
```

Actually, if you want to be curt about it, this could be changed to:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {
```

if you're declaring the method.

You can access the meta data about a managed object by accessing its entity:

```
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [managedObject entity];
```

From there, get a description of each property:

```
  NSDictionary *descriptions = [entity propertiesByName];
```

This dictionary will have all the keys you want in your dictionary, and an `NSAttributeDescription` or an `NSRelationshipDescription` as the value.

**The fact that you have written custom classes to provide functionality on these classes is irrelevant!** You can access all the data in them regardless of whether they are `NSManagedObject` instances, or subclasses thereof.

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, use [object_getClassName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getClassName) to get the `char*` name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing, but are you looking for the `isKindOfClass:` method?

From the [`NSObject` Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a):

```
NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:30];
id anArchiver = [[NSArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:myData];
if ( [anArchiver isKindOfClass:[NSCoder class]] )
    ...
```

Also, you ***are*** casting properly.  This is the correct way to cast an object to type `MyClass`:

```
MyClass *myObject = (MyClass *)obj;
```

If nothing here has helped can you show the errors you are getting or what exactly is not working?

Comment: I think his problem is that he wants to access a bunch of the properties of the object, but he can't do that without first determining its class and casting the pointer.

Comment: no, i am looking to not have to do a "crap load of if statements" to determine ( via isKindOfClass: ) the class of the object. And apparently the class generated with NSClassFromString cannot be used in this method. It is not seen as a normal class.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, I don't think you can cast an object in Obj-C, but you can cast the pointer to another class (that's probably what you mean, Sorry to be nit-picky).

I'm not sure offhand how to handle the casting in a programmatically smart way, but if you have a reasonable number of classes you can just use conditional blocks to handle the different cases:

```
if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
  ...
} else if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[MyOtherClass class]]) {
...
}
```

If the code in each of these blocks is largely (or even partially) the same, you can always add a superclass between NSManagedObject and your classes that contains the common code, so you can start by casting the pointer to that superclass, handle the common stuff, and still dive into conditionals if necessary.

I'm sure someone else will swoop in with a smarter answer, but there are my thoughts. Goof luck!

Comment: the thing that sets my custom NSManagedObjects apart are the different attributes between them. I thought of doing the superclass route but then realized that I would then just have the same issue in a different place. I think the best route is when that object needs this method to just pass a dictionary into the method created, rather than the object itself. this way I can guaranty the attributes i need are there.

Comment: What about using respondsToSelector to test whether the attributes are available?